# Alternatives to a ManytoManyField for static/hardcoded data?

Tags: python, django

I'm building a Django app in which I need to represent gender (male/female) for all users. A single user can select that they are interested in males, females, or both. This data will then be used to cross-reference with other users to find similarities. A ManytoManyField for gender will clearly work, but since gender is a fairly static field that will only have two options, is there a better way to implement this? Is there some sort of multiple-selection capable field that doesn't require the database overheard of a m2m field?

Comment: as the answers say, `choices` is what you want.  but really `choices` only works instead of `ForeignKey`.  what if the person is both male and female?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely shy away from an M2M - that will get expensive and just plain difficult to query over time with tons of double underscore notation. For static stuff, you specifically want `choices`.

One of the more useful coding practices I've learned over the years is an idea from James Bennets blog is the way he uses choices: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/nov/02/handle-choices-right-way/

Basically, let lets you do this:

```
class MyObject(models.Model):
    MALE = 0
    FEMALE = 1
    ROBOT = 2
    MY_CHOICES = [
        (MALE, 'Male'),
        (FEMALE, 'Female'),
        (ROBOT, 'Robot'),
    ]
    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=MY_CHOICES)


MyObject.objects.filter(gender=MyObject.ROBOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can store a string or an int, and restrict the possible values using [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices)

Comment: Alternatively, you could use two boolean fields: interest in men and in women. You might have a little form-tuning for it to be more user-friendly, but I think it makes more sense from a DB perspective.